# C++ random number generation, range of [0...n], as quick and lazy as possible?

Tags: c++, random

`<random>` has a ton of engine and distribution options.  This is good and all, but most documentation I've read treats every engine and distribution with equal attention, and made no effort to suggest usage or useful instances for certain use-cases.  I usually just use `rand()` to get useful data quickly, but I'm trying to be a better C++ programmer!  (plus, getting useful floats out of `rand()` in a certain range can be it's own head ache sometimes)

My question is, what is the quickest and laziest way to instance a random number generator in C++ that will do random numbers (floats, to pick a type) in the range [0...n] without any quirky surprises?

**edit:**

Watching the presentation on random mentioned in the comments, I realize the engine and distribution I needed was `mt199937` and `uniform_real_distribution`.  I wasn't sure which was the mersenne twister, but seeing the 'mt' it's pretty obvious now.  Combining the two concepts also makes sense now.  Here is what I'm using in case anyone else comes across this:

```
std::mt19937 randomEngine(seed);
std::uniform_real_distribution<float> range(0, n);

float randomResult = range(randomEngine);
```

Comment: [This presentation](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful) will tell you everything you need :)

Comment: [Random Number Generation is Not Simple!](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3847.pdf) proposes to add some simple `rand`-like functions to C++ that use `<random>`. You can copy one of their proposed implementations. The "function template toolkit" looks like it would do.

Comment: It's not that hard, see the example in [this `std::uniform_real_distribution` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_real_distribution). It's just three lines to set it all up, which you need to do only once.

Comment: @Quentin - Ah, I seen that presentation before.  It's what got me to stop using `rand()`.  Now if only I wasn't so simple that I had to relearn how <random> worked every time I needed it

Comment: Well, craft yourself a couple of functions and reuse them between projects. Like, one that creates, seeds and return an mt19937, and one that takes it along with two floats and picks one at random.

Comment: @Josep I agree with the premise of that paper but I have to say that I’m not too happy with their proposed solution(s). Besides the infernal `default_random_engine` (or was that improved in C++14?), it proposes making the state global (again), which will encourage its use in libraries and will thus directly lead to bad code (libraries sharing user state – great!). And the proposed classes have a much too big and un-opinionated interface, which basically means they just re-package all the original functionality, badly (in one master class instead logical functions).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Watch Stephan T. Lavavej’s talk [**`rand()` considered harmful**](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful), it will answer all your questions and more.

In particular:

- To generate uniform random numbers between 0 and n, use

  ```
  std::random_device dev;
  std::mt19937 gen{dev()};
  std::uniform_real_distribution<T> dist{0, n};
  ```

  This uses the predefined [`mt19937`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/mersenne_twister_engine) engine, which is a good default and should be used in all cases where there’s no strong argument against it.

  For seeding, use [`std::random_device`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/random_device) unless you need a reproducible seed.
- Do **not** use `std::default_random_engine`, since it is under-specified: there is no control over what engine it is using, and it is not portable.
- To shuffle a sequence of elements, use [`std::shuffle`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle), do **not** use `std::random_shuffle` any more, consider it deprecated.